# Simple HTTP response: why does this work with Python2 but not with Python3

Tags: python, http, curl

With the following code, running with:

```
uwsgi --socket myapp.sock --plugins /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python_plugin.so \
--module wsgi --chmod-socket=664
```

I don't understand why this gives me GET and POST values printed by curl nicely when using /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python_plugin.so but not when using /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python**3**_plugin.so

I'm using curl as follows: `curl -v --form 'file=@testfile;filename=newfilename' --form 'q=c'  localhost?q=x`

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])

    try:
        request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
    except (ValueError):
        request_body_size = 0

    request_body = environ.get('wsgi.input', b'').read(request_body_size).decode('utf-8')
    get_values = environ.get('QUERY_STRING', '')

    return ["Hello There!\n\n" + request_body + get_values]
```

I added the decode('utf-8') to convert from bytes to string in Python3. When working with Python2 I left this out.

Comment: what is the error that is output??

Comment: There is no error, and no output. Also when I return a string instead of []

Comment: your `def application()` function must be running somewhere.. with the application running in one terminal and calling curl in another window - your saying there is no output at all in the application terminal?

Comment: No, Only the access log: [pid: 1141|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 533 bytes} [Wed Jan  9 13:05:32 2019] POST /?q=x => generated 341 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

Comment: But I found the problem, I'll answer my own question now below.

Comment: cool.. glad you found your issue, i must say it feels more satisfactory when I discover my own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
return ["Hello There!\n\n" + request_body + get_values]
```

changed to:

```
return [("Hello There!\n\n" + request_body + get_values).encode('utf-8')]
```

makes it work.